# Skip certain table on DbContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create the database using the

```
_ctx.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

where _ctx is my database context. There are some system tables in the project mapped to the context, like:

```
public class SchemaColumnMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SchemaColumn>
{
    public SchemaColumnMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(k => new { k.TABLE_NAME, k.COLUMN_NAME });
        this.ToTable("COLUMNS", "INFORMATION_SCHEMA");

    }
}
```

When it tries to create the schema, it gets following error:

> The specified schema name "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

Looking into sql profiler I see it tries to create the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table:

```
CREATE TABLE [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] (
[TABLE_NAME] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[COLUMN_NAME] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[ORDINAL_POSITION] [int] NOT NULL,
[COLUMN_DEFAULT] [nvarchar](max),
[IS_NULLABLE] [nvarchar](max),
[DATA_TYPE] [nvarchar](max),
[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] [int],
[NUMERIC_PRECISION] [tinyint],
[NUMERIC_SCALE] [int],
CONSTRAINT [PK_INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS] PRIMARY KEY ([TABLE_NAME], [COLUMN_NAME])
```

which fails as expected. My question is: can I somehow skip this table creation while other schema creating? I can't drop SchemaColumn from the model nor .Ignore() it, this is existing project and all I need is to add code-first approach.

Comment: Generate explicit migration and remove the unneeded stuff.